# Code splitting using webpack for example https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to code splitting of several routes together. For ex home and widgets in bundle1.js, survery and about in bundle2.js and login in bundle3.js.

So that when I refresh home page it will load only bundle1.js, on going to widgets page it will show widgets without getting additional files as Single page application.

When user clicks on survery it will download bundle2.js and show that page and so on. In this process page size will be kept low even as grows larger.

Production webpack link is https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/webpack/prod.config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed https://github.com/bertho-zero/react-redux-universal-hot-example boilerplate, its updated and do code splitting with webpack 2

Comment: I recently upgraded to react-router 4, still with SSR, code-splitting and data-fetching.

Answer (score 1):

If defining split points with Webpack 1 you'll be able to pass a name for your split point allowing you to have multiple split points compile into a single chunk, e.g.

```
require.ensure([], () => {
    const Home = require('./home');
    // render Home.
}, 'bundle1');

require.ensure([], () => {
    const Widgets = require('./widgets');
    // render Widgets.
}, 'bundle1');

require.ensure([], () => {
    const Survey = require('./survey');
    // render Home.
}, 'bundle2');
```

The above will result in just two chunks, i.e.:

- bundle1.js
- bundle2.js

Unfortunately if you're using Webpack 2 with `System.import()` / `import()` instead of `require.ensure` it's not possible to name your chunks however there is talk of being able to provide config to the same effect here -- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1949